# What is better for performance: event for each element or one event with delegation?

Tags: javascript, performance, dom-events

I need to make big table (for example, 100x100) with input elements in each cell. What will be better for performance: to create event for each input element or to create event for table and use event delegation (propagation)?

I feel like a lot of events will slow down everything, but will delegation be better? I am thinking also about something like creating and removing events dynamically for only visible elements or similar.

Comment: interesting, I would like to know as well. Why don't you create a POC and share the result?

Comment: @orhor Can you please explain, what is POC?

Comment: When you say "use capture", are you referring to event delegation?

Comment: sorry - a proof of concept, a solution for testing purposes

Comment: @zzzzBov Yes, delegation from outermost to innermost elements. That's called capturing in javascript as far as I know.

Comment: @Somnium, no, "capturing" is a phase in the order that events are triggered. The other phase being "bubbling". You might choose to implement delegation during the capturing phase, but it's not the appropriate term for using a single event handler to listen for events triggered by child elements. The proper term for that is "event delegation".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you attach an event handler to the table, you can get the event target, which will contain the element that was actually triggered the event. It will have much less performance impact than applying multiple events.

Note that not all events bubble, so this technique doesn’t work with all event types.